# Trouble with a GUI toolkit in C++. Passing lambdas into a vector of std::function

Tags: c++, function, vector, window, controls

The problem I have is kind of difficult to describe but I will do my best to make it understandable.

I am creating a C++ GUI toolkit similar to the Windows Forms System in C#. The whole system is event based. My `Event` class consists of a vector of `std::function`'s, which acts as a list of subscriber functions, and some utility methods.

```
template<class T>
class Event
{
public:

  Event() {}
  ~Event() {}

  void Raise(T context)
  {
    for(std::function<void(T&)> subscriber : Subscribers)
    {
      subscriber(context);
    }
  }

  void Subscribe(std::function<void(T&)> subscriber)
  {
    try { Subscribers.push_back(subscriber); } catch (std::exception) { /*...*/ }
  }

private:

  std::vector<std::function<void(T&)>>> Subscribers;

}
```

My project contains an `EventProvider` class which provides a bunch of events to all derived classes.

```
class EventProvider
{
public:

  Event<LoadEventContext> LoadEvent;
  // ...
  // ...

}
```

Also like in Windows Forms I have a `Window` class and a `Control` class. Both of them inherit `EventProvider`. Like in C# the actual Window class where all functionalities are defined must inherit the `Window` class.

```
class Control : public EventProvider { /*...*/ }

class Window : public EventProvider { /*...*/ }

class MyWindow : public Window { /*...*/ }
```

In my `MyWindow` class I am binding methods to the events of the Window via lambdas. Binding methods of the `MyWindow` class to events of the `MyWindow` class works just fine. Also binding a control's member function to an event of `MyWindow` works without problems. In Windows Forms all event methods of the controls are also contained in the Window class. The same I wanted to do in my project. So the `MyWindow` class contains the instances of my controls, it's own event methods and the event methods of my controls. But when I try to bind a control event function to a control event I am getting a runtime error.

```
// ===  MyWindow.hpp  ===

#ifndef __MY_WINDOW_HPP__
#define __MY_WINDOW_HPP__

#include <Control.hpp>
#include <Window.hpp>

class MyWindow : public Window
{
public:

  MyWindow();
  ~MyWindow();

private:

  Control* button = nullptr;

  void OnLoadEvent(LoadEventContext& context);
  void button_OnLoadEvent(LoadEventContext& context);

}

#endif



// ===  MyWindow.cpp ===

#include <MyWindow.hpp>

MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
  button = new Control();

  LoadEvent.Subscribe([&](LoadEventContext& context) { OnLoadEvent(context); }); // WORKS
  LoadEvent.Subscribe([&](LoadEventContext& context) { button->OnLoadEvent(context); }); // WORKS

  button->OnLoadEvent.Subscribe([&](LoadEventContext& context) { OnLoadEvent(context); }); // Runtime Error
}

MyWindow::~MyWindow() { /*...*/ }

MyWindow::OnLoadEvent(LoadEventContext& context) { /*...*/ }

MyWindow::button_OnLoadEvent(LoadEventContext& context) { /*...*/ }

//
```

When `MyWindow` calls the control's load event to add the lambda function to the event's vector of subscriber functions a read access violation is thrown in the stl's `vector` class.

[image]

This line of code called the event to add the lambda function:

```
button->OnLoadEvent.Subscribe([&](LoadEventContext& context) { OnLoadEvent(context); }); // Runtime Error
```

and this one in the `Event` class caused the error:

```
try { Subscribers.push_back(subscriber); } catch (std::exception) { /*...*/ }
```

I am still not very advanced in programming with function pointers, functors, functionoids and all that stuff. Nevertheless I hope I pointed out my problem clearly enough for you and I hope that anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: What line of your code caused this? Use the Stack Frame on the toolbar to figure out.

Comment: You probably want to show the implementation of `Subscribe()` and `OnLoadEvent()`

Comment: The implementation of `Subscribe()` is pointed out in the `Event` class and `OnLoadEvent()` is currently empty.

Comment: I'm sorry but I had to reduce the complexity of the whole system to 10% for this post.

Comment: Don't add `solved` to the question title. Press the green tick on the left of your answer to mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. The problem was that I bound my event method the event of my control before this control has been created at all.